# Stream map '0:a:0' matches no streams

Tags: ffmpeg

To encode a video using FFMPEG the following command is used:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i INPUT.MP4 
-preset veryfast -r 25 -g 75 -threads 4 -sc_threshold 0 
-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 
-filter:v:0 scale=h=240:w=-2  
-minrate:v:0 75k  
-maxrate:v:0 218k  
-bufsize:v:0 300k 
-b:v:0 150k  -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0" 
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 
-f hls -hls_time 3 -segment_time 6 
-hls_list_size 0 -segment_format mpegts 
-hls_segment_filename /res-%v/segment-%d.ts  OUTPUT.M3U8  1> log.txt 2>&1
```

In general, despite such a huge command, it copes with the task with a bang

But there is one little BUT:

If you run this command on a video WITHOUT audio, there will be an error:

```
Stream map '0:a:0' matches no streams. To ignore this, add a trailing '?' to the map.
```

Yes, I understand that the command tells me that the audio stream was not found. And to ignore this, you need to add a trailing question mark to the map

But only I can’t understand where? to which place?

I will be glad to any advice or suggestion

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Use `-map 0:a:0?`, as in:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i INPUT.MP4 
-preset veryfast -r 25 -g 75 -threads 4 -sc_threshold 0 
-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0? 
-filter:v:0 scale=h=240:w=-2  
-minrate:v:0 75k  
-maxrate:v:0 218k  
-bufsize:v:0 300k 
-b:v:0 150k  -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0" 
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 
-f hls -hls_time 3 -segment_time 6 
-hls_list_size 0 -segment_format mpegts 
-hls_segment_filename /res-%v/segment-%d.ts  OUTPUT.M3U8  1> log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Unfortunately HLS does not gracefully ignore missing streams specified in var_stream_map.

Comment: Not a bug. HLS muxer is part of lavf so it isn't exclusively used by fftools. `-map` with its ? qualifier is specifically fftools. So, in this case, the muxer has been told to expect an audio stream but none is registered in the AVFormatContext. Maybe ? parsing could be added to the muxer.